# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte "0xc3"

Tags: python

In python 2.7 I have this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from nltk.corpus import abc
with open("abc.txt","w") as f:
    f.write(" ".join(i.words()))
```

I then try to read in this document in Python 3:

```
 with open("abc.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
     f.read()
```

only to get:

```
  File "C:\Python32\lib\codecs.py", line 300, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 633096: invalid continuation byte
```

What have I done wrong? Notepad++ seems to indicate that the document is Unicode utf-8. Even if I try to convert the document to this format with Notepad++ I still get this error in python 3, which is strange since I read many other utf-8 encoded documents without any problems.

Comment: What does `od` say about the characters around that position?

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that your input is encoded as ISO-8859-2 which contains `Ă` as `0xC3`. Check the encoding of your input file.

Comment: Notepad++ says that the document is encoded as UTF8 without BOM

Comment: @Baz Notepad++ can guess wrong. There is *no* reliable way to guess an encoding. Every program will sometimes guess the wrong encoding, that's why you should always *know* the encoding of a file. Try to re-write the file making the encoding to utf-8 explicit(e.g. using `codecs.open` instead of `open`).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the fact that your piece of Python 2.7 doesn't throw an exception, I would infer that `i.words()` returns a sequence of bytestrings. These are unlikely to be encoded in UTF8 - I'd guess maybe Latin-1 or something like that. You then write them to the file. No encoding happens at this point.

You probably need to convert these to unicode strings, for which you'll need to know their existing encoding, and then you'll need to encode these as UTF-8 when writing the file.

For example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from nltk.corpus import abc
import codecs
with codecs.open("abc.txt","w","utf-8") as f:
    f.write(u" ".join(codecs.decode(word,"latin-1") for word in i.words()))
```

---

Some further notes, in case there's any confusion:

- The `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` line refers to the encoding used to write the Python script itself. It has no effect on the input or output of that script.
- In Python 2.7, there are two kinds of strings: bytestrings, which are sequences of bytes with an unspecified encoding, and unicode strings, which are sequences of unicode code points. Bytestrings are most common and are what you get if you use the regular `"abc"` string literal syntax. Unicode strings are what you get when you use the `u"abc"` syntax.
- In Python 2.7, if you just use the open function to open a file and write bytestrings to it, no encoding will happen. The bytes of the bytestring are written straight into the file. If you try to write unicode strings to it, you'll get an exception if they contain characters that can't be encoded by the default (ASCII) codec.