# pandas read_csv encoding weird character

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8, pandas

I tried to read my dataset in text file format using pandas. However, some characters are not encoded correctly. I got ??? for apostrophe.

What should I do to encode my file correctly? I've tried

- `encoding = "utf8"` but I got `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2044: unexpected end of data`.
- `encoding = "latin1"` but this gave me a lot of ???
- `encoding = "ISO-8859-1" or "ISO-8859-2"` but this also gave me just like no encoding...

When I open my data in sublime, I got this character â€™.

UPDATED: But when I access the entry using loc I got something like \u0102\u02d8\xe2\x82\u0179\xc2\u015, \u0102\u02d8\xe2\x82\u0179\xe2\x84\u02d8

Comment: You need to know what encoding the file is actually in.  Where did you get the file?

Comment: have you tried ISO-8859-2?

Comment: @AndyHayden Yes, I did

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to [determine the encoding](https://superuser.com/questions/301552/how-to-auto-detect-text-file-encoding) with [chardet](http://chardet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
$ pip install chardet

>>> import urllib
>>> rawdata = urllib.urlopen('http://yahoo.co.jp/').read()
>>> import chardet
>>> chardet.detect(rawdata)
{'encoding': 'EUC-JP', 'confidence': 0.99}
```

*The basic usage also suggests how you can use this to infer the encoding from large files e.g. files too large to read into memory - it'll read the file until it's confident enought about the encoding.*

---

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403898/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xc3) you should try `encoding="ISO-8859-2"`:

> My guess is that your input is encoded as ISO-8859-2 which contains Ă as `0xC3`.

---

*Note: Sublime may not infer the encoding correctly either so you have to take it's output with a pinch of salt, it's best to check with your vendor (wherever you're getting the file from) what the actual encoding is...*

Comment: @user3362840 please try chardet :)