# Python: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python

Current code:

```
 file.write("\"" + key + "\": " + "\"" + french[key].encode('utf8') + "\"" + ',' + '\n')
```

where french key values in dictionary look like this:

```
"YOU_HAVE_COMPLETED_ENROLLMENT": "Vous avez termin\u00e9 l'inscription !"
```

Getting this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Tried all the solutions on here but none seem to work.

Comment: same error it looks like still

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python encoding utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092437/python-encoding-utf-8)

Comment: looked at that thread and it says to just write it directly without encoding. However, if i remove .encode, it gives me an encode error: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 37: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403898/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xc3

Comment: @Justin. (1) Are you using python2 or python 3? (2) what is the output of `print(type(french[key]))` (3) what is `file`, and how did you create it?

Comment: @ekhumoro (1) On mac, getting python version 2.7. (2) output of print returns <type 'unicode'> (3) file is created through this line: file = open(os.path.join(fr_directory, 'strings.json'), 'w+')

Comment: @Justin. I have tried the code in your question and it does not produce any errors when using python-2.7. Please check it and make sure you copy/paste the actual code that is causing the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: special characters giving me problems (from PDFminer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870214/python-special-characters-giving-me-problems-from-pdfminer)

Answer (score 1):

The solution: Concatenate unicode strings *before* encoding, then encode the complete string just before writing to a file. The `codecs` library simplifies this for you.

```
import codecs

file = codecs.open(os.path.join(fr_directory, 'strings.json'), 'w+', encoding='utf8')
file.write("\"" + key + "\": " + "\"" + french[key] + "\"" + ',' + '\n')
```

I have opened the file with `codecs.open` rather than just `open`, specifying that the file should automatically handle encoding into UTF-8 when you write unicode strings. I have also removed the explicit encoding call you used.

### Further explanation:

The keys and values of your dictionary are almost certainly Unicode strings. A "Unicode string" needs to be encoded before it can be written to a file. Most operations in Python 2 assume an ASCII encoding unless told otherwise, and the file objects returned by `open` are among them. That's why, if you try to write a Unicode string to a file, you'll see an exception:

```
>>> with open('/tmp/test.txt', 'w') as f:
...    f.write(u"Vous avez termin\xe9 l'inscription !")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This error is one that you can fix by encoding the string directly, so this works:

```
>>> with open('/tmp/test.txt', 'w') as f:
...    f.write(u"Vous avez termin\xe9 l'inscription !".encode('utf-8'))
```

However, this alone does not solve your problem, because you are trying to build a more complicated string. When you concatenate a Unicode string to a UTF-8 encoded "raw" string, you also get an exception, even when not writing to a file:

```
>>> u"YOU_HAVE_COMPLETED_ENROLLMENT: " + u"Vous avez termin\xe9 l'inscription !".encode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

You can fix this by *not* encoding either string:

```
>>> u"YOU_HAVE_COMPLETED_ENROLLMENT: " + u"Vous avez termin\xe9 l'inscription !"
u"YOU_HAVE_COMPLETED_ENROLLMENT: Vous avez termin\xe9 l'inscription !"
```

But then when you want to write it to a file, you would have to encode the whole thing again:

```
>>> with open('/tmp/test.txt', 'w') as f:
...    line = u"YOU_HAVE_COMPLETED_ENROLLMENT: " + u"Vous avez termin\xe9 l'inscription !"
...    f.write(line.encode('utf-8'))
```

But for convenience, the `codecs` module gives you the tools to not always have to re-encode every time:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> with codecs.open('/tmp/test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
...    f.write(u"YOU_HAVE_COMPLETED_ENROLLMENT: " + u"Vous avez termin\xe9 l'inscription !")
```

Answer (score 1):

you could unicode string using this function

```
def _parse_value(value):
    if type(value) == str:
        value = value.decode("utf-8", "ignore").strip()
    return value
```